# What exactly is wrong with my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

My program compiles, but when I run it, it gives me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I am wondering what is wrong with it as I am unable to see it. My program is supposed to take input by the user and add it to the ArrayList. I am sorry if my mistake is obvious to you, but I am relatively new at using ArrayLists. Thanks!

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
int counter = 0;
int i = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = in.nextInt();

while(i < 5)
{
    input = in.nextInt();
    if(input != 0){
        arr.get(i).set(counter++, input);
    }
    else{
        arr.get(i).set(counter++, input);
        i++;
        counter = 0;
    }
}

System.out.println(arr);
```

Comment: You never add anything to `arr`.  What do you expect `arr.get(i)` to do when called on an empty `List`?

Comment: why do you want a nested arraylist?

Comment: are you trying to create an arraylist with no negative numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s, initially, there are no `ArrayList`s contained in `arr`.  So any call to `get` will fail with a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

First, add the initial inner `ArrayList` to `arr`.

Then, in the `while` loop, `get` the current inner `ArrayList` as you're doing, but just call `add` to append a number to the end of the list.  Otherwise, you'll get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on your inner `ArrayList`.  Again, the `ArrayList` you've created is initially empty.

When the user enters `0`, then `add` another `ArrayList` when you're incrementing `i` (unless `i` is already at the last desired value), to prepare for the user adding numbers to the next list.

Comment: So, if I were to make the initial creation of the ArrayList      `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(5);` would that work? Because I'm still getting an IndexOutOfBoundsError.

Comment: No, that just sets the initial _capacity_ of the outer `ArrayList` to 5.  If you were to make only that change to your code, then there still wouldn't be anything in the outer `ArrayList`.  You can make that change if you want, but you'd still need to make the changes in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of list and both are empty. Also you are using "set" method which is actually used to replace the object in a list on specific location.

So it looks like you wanted to take input from user and if the value is 0 you just wanted to ignore it. Below is the update example for you.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int i = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = 0;
    while(i < 5){
        input = in.nextInt();
        if(input != 0){
            arr.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            arr.get(i).add(input);
            i++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(arr);
```

If you just want to create a list of integers then you don't have need to create a list of list. You can achieve by creating a list of integer only.

```
 ArrayList<Integer>  arr = new ArrayList< Integer >();
    int i = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = 0;
    while(i < 5){
        input = in.nextInt();
        if(input != 0){
            arr.add(input);
            i++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(arr);
```